# How to get the transaction cost in a Truffle unit test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, gas, testing, gas-price

How can I get the actual gas consumed by a `sendTransaction` inside a truffle test?

In the following test, `buyer` sends an `amount` of 50 ETH to a contract:

```
const EmptyContract = artifacts.require("EmptyContract");
const BigNumber = web3.BigNumber;

contract('Test', function(accounts) {   
    it("should work", async () => {
        let contract = await EmptyContract.new({ from: accounts[1] });
        let amount = web3.toWei(50, 'ether');
        let buyer = accounts[2];

        // BALANCE BEFORE TX
        let balanceBefore = web3.eth.getBalance(buyer);

        // SEND TX
        let hash = await contract.buy.sendTransaction({from: buyer, value: amount});

        // BALANCE AFTER TX
        const balanceAfter = web3.eth.getBalance(buyer);

        let tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(hash);
        const gasUsed = tx.gas;
        const gasCost = tx.gasPrice.mul(gasUsed);
        console.log("BEFORE", balanceBefore.toNumber());
        console.log("amount sent", amount);
        console.log("gas price", tx.gasPrice.toNumber());
        console.log("gas used", gasUsed);
        console.log("gas cost", gasCost.toNumber());
        console.log("AFTER", balanceAfter.toNumber());
        console.log("CHECKSUM", balanceAfter.add(gasCost).add(amount).toNumber());

        assert.equal(balanceBefore.toNumber(), balanceAfter.add(gasCost).add(amount).toNumber());
    });
});
```

Then `buyer`'s balance is checked. It should be

**[balance before tx] = [balance after tx] + [amount sent] + [gas cost]**

But it fails, printing:

```
BEFORE 100000000000000000000
amount sent 50000000000000000000
gas price 100000000000
gas used 6721975
gas cost 672197500000000000
AFTER 49997862200000000000
CHECKSUM 100670059700000000000       
   :    
AssertionError: expected 100000000000000000000 to equal 100670059700000000000
```

The contract is very basic:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract EmptyContract {
    function buy() public payable  { }
}
```

It seems that the transaction cost 0.6700597 ETH less than the value returned by `tx`.

I followed [Transaction gas cost in truffle test case](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41858/transaction-gas-cost-in-truffle-test-case) but it didn't help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to multiply the `gasUsed` for the `gasPrice`. The `gasUsed` is contained into the transaction receipt. While the `gasPrice` is into the transaction itself. Indeed, in your case, you're trying to multiply the `gasPrice` for the `gas`, which is the one provided by the sender (which can be higher that the `gasUsed`). ref: [getTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction), [getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt)

So, this is how your code should look like to be correct

```
const hash = await contract.buy.sendTransaction({from: buyer, value: amount});

// BALANCE AFTER TX
const balanceAfter = web3.eth.getBalance(buyer);
const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(hash);
const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
const gasCost = tx.gasPrice.mul(receipt.gasUsed);
```

or you can also actually save the `getTransactionReceipt` call in case you call your method directly (in this case should give you a result that contains also the transaction receipt [ref](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#processing-transaction-results))

```
const txInfo = await contract.buy({from: buyer, value: amount});

// BALANCE AFTER TX
const balanceAfter = web3.eth.getBalance(buyer);
const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txInfo.tx);
const gasCost = tx.gasPrice.mul(txInfo.receipt.gasUsed);
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't get why `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash).gas` and `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).gasUsed` are different. What's the meaning of the former?

Comment: As I've explained in the post `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash).gas` is the value provided by the user. While `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash).gasUsed` is the gas used by the transaction. So `gas` must to be >= `gasUsed` in order to execute the transaction. Of course you couldn't know before how much gas your transaction will use, that's why user must to increase the gas in order to be sure that the transaction would be executed. `gasUsed` is often <= `gas` and the difference (not used gas) is refunded immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: you can use [truffle-cost](https://github.com/guix77/truffle-cost). It allows you to log transaction costs instead of test duration, with a syntax like this:

```
result = await truffleCost.log(
  yourContract.yourFunction()
);
```

Please see link for installation (or should I explain in here?).

Disclaimer: I'm truffle-cost's developer.